# How can you burn your hunger bar the fastest in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a TON of food and I want to eat it all but I need to deplete my hunger bar first. How can I burn my hunger bar down in the shortest time possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to get rid of your food instead of saving it for when you need it?

Comment: Or rather, why not just throw it in some lava and accomplish the same thing as purposely exhausting yourself and eating food just to eat it?

Comment: And if disposal is absolutely necessary, why isn't throwing it into lava or down a pit easier?

Answer (score 26):

In my experience, [sprinting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sprinting) while jumping around depletes the hunger bar more rapidly than anything else I do. This is confirmed by [this Exhaustion Level chart](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Food_Bar#Exhaustion_level_increase) taken from the wiki:

[image]

*NOTE: Any action not listed here will not increase exhaustion level. For example, the player can travel several days by boat and the food bar will not decrease.*

Food poisoning seems to work rather effectively as well, so chow down on all the [Rotten Flesh](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rotten_Flesh) and [Raw Chicken](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raw_Chicken) you can find for additional exhaustion while you sprint and jump around like a madman.

Comment: It's worth-noting that food poisoning effect does not stack. Chewing poisoning food one after another is more effective.

Comment: Note that spider eyes and poison potatoes don't give food poisoning, they give actual poisoning.

Comment: @Random832: Oops, missed that. Fixed now.

Comment: You can poison yourself and then do sprinting jumps. Efficiency!

Comment: @Alex Remember to do the food poisoned sprintjumping in a downhill slope with a suitable angle of declination, so that you take half a heart of fall damage each time you land.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get rid of your food, i would sugest getting a wolf and then feed him all the food (wolves don't get full). But if you actually need to EAT it, try sprinting, jumping, mining, and also climb up a little hill and jump down so you take like 3 hearts of damage. In my opinion, feeding it to your wolves is best. Hope it helps!

Comment: Does damage make you hungrier? I haven't noticed that.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I believe that it does, it just does so little that you barely notice it.

Answer (score 3):

One of the fastest and easiest ways is to stand under a block right above you and then tap the spacebar as fast as you can. It would go faster if you could sprint while doing it.

Comment: "It would go faster if you could sprint while doing it." - if only there were some arrangement of blocks that could be used for this and also be useful for something. Maybe some kind of tunnel, that's exactly two blocks tall.

Comment: @Random832: Don't be daft, man; that kind of thing is pure sci-fi. Why, that would only be possible if you could remove and rearrange blocks, somehow. I don't know about you, but *I'm* certainly not holding my breath.

Comment: @Random832 A tunnel of ice with trapdoors on top will rapidly deplete a hunger bar while sprint-jumping down it.

Answer (score -3):

You should first eat rotting zombie flesh, sprint and jump in the same time while attacking a monster. Also, if you just want space in your inventory, throw some of your food in the lava. This way helps you save time and score.

Comment: Are you seriously just restating another answer? Come on, there's enough [unanswered questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/unanswered) where your help is actually required